# My class isn't defined. Python Pygame

Tags: python-3.x, class, pygame

I was just starting a rougelike game in python pygame when I came across an error I didn't under stand.
Here's the code:

**Main.py**

```
import pygame
import Textures

pygame.init()

Tiles_Size = 32
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

def create_window():
    global window
   window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600),pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
   pygame.display.set_caption('RPG')

create_window()

isRunning = True

while isRunning:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a: #Switch to K_A rather than pygame.K_a
                isRunning = False # for glitch! :)

    window.fill(BLACK)

    for x in range(0, 640, Tiles.Size):
        for y in range(0, 480, Tiles.Size):
            window.blit(Tiles.Wood, (x, y))


pygame.quit()
```

**Textures.py**

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

class Tiles:

    Size = 32

    def Load_Texture(file, Size):
        bitmap = pygame.image.load(file)
        bitmap = pygame.transform.scale(bitmap, (Size, Size))
        surface = pygame.Surface((Size, Size), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.SRCALPHA)
        surface.blit(bitmap, (0, 0))
        return surface

    Wood = Load_Texture("Graphics\\wood.jpg", Size)
```

That's all the code I have and the files go as follows

```
Graphics
    wood.jpg
main.py
textures.py
```

So the error was quite odd. When I ran the `main.py` file, the error was rather weird. With the variables `Tiles.Size` and `Tiles.Wood`, it said the `Tiles` class in the `textures.py` file was not defined when it quite clearly is there! I got stuck with this glitch for a while and gave up. Then I looked at it again and I still can't find the error. The Error was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*********\Desktop\PygameRPG\Main.py", line 26, in <module>
    for x in range(0, 640, Tiles.Size):
NameError: name 'Tiles' is not defined
```

That's my Error.

Some help would be great!

Comment: `Tiles` is defined in textures.py, so when you  import textures, you should call  `Textures.Tiles.Size`

Comment: I've already tried doing that!

Comment: Forgot to type that, Im gonna edit!

Comment: please try with `Textures.Tiles.Size`

Answer (score 0):

You imported Textures.py in main.py but you forgot something! If you want to do this:

`for x in range(0, 640, Tiles().Size):`

You should neither do this:

```
from textures import *
```

nor change the code to this:

`for x in range(0, 640, textures.Tiles().Size):`

You also forgot parentheses. Now, try this codes as this, it must work:

main.py:

```
import pygame
import textures

pygame.init()

Tiles_Size = 32
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

def create_window():
   global window
   window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600),pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
   pygame.display.set_caption('RPG')

create_window()

isRunning = True

while isRunning:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a: #Switch to K_A rather than pygame.K_a
                isRunning = False # for glitch! :)

    window.fill(BLACK)

    for x in range(0, 640, textures.TilesClass().Size):
        for y in range(0, 480, textures.TilesClass().Size):
            window.blit(textures.TilesClass().Wood, (x, y))
```

textures.py:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

class TilesClass:

    Size = 32

    def Load_Texture(file, Size):
        bitmap = pygame.image.load(file)
        bitmap = pygame.transform.scale(bitmap, (Size, Size))
        surface = pygame.Surface((Size, Size), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.SRCALPHA)
        surface.blit(bitmap, (0, 0))
        return surface

    Wood = Load_Texture("Graphics\\wood.jpg", Size)
```

Comment: When I switch it from `import Textures` to `from Textures import *`, I didn't get an error but the grid of wood didn't appear either. When I did `Textures.Tiles.Size` or `Textures.Tiles.Wood` It said `NameError: name 'Textures' is not defined`

Comment: Can you change the name 'Textures' to something more unique? Like 'mytexturesbutgood' and then try again?

Comment: Hmm, Just tried this and the same things happened! :(

Comment: Okay, you are sure importing textures.py without the capital 'T' right?

Comment: Yes, Defiantely!

Comment: We are just missing something so simple and basic.

Comment: I updated the answer, please try now. I am pretty sure it will work.

Comment: I added parentheses, imported right, and also changed `Tiles` to `TilesClass`. Just to be sure if Tiles is a keyword in pygame or not.

Comment: Sorry for not answering for a while. While this answer didn't give me an error, it didn't give me my wooden grid. Just black.

Comment: I'm sorry I could not help %100 :(  I do not know much about Pygame, so I won't be able to say why your wooden grid is not showing up. I hope you keep researching and find the correct answer, and maybe lighten me up then too!